# Transfer Account Owner, Keep Account Team

Tags: account, ownership, account-teams

I want to retain the Account Team whenever the `OwnerId` changes, as per [this post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/68834/account-team-member-lost-when-account-owner-changes).

After we make the checkbox named "Keep Account Team" to be true, we can change the ownership of accounts while locking all the associated account teams.

But I am not able to find any field in the org even though I have Unlimited Edition.

Also, here is a post for [retaining the Account Team via SOQL](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/79130/how-to-set-account-team-owner).

Please suggest as the second methodology seems to be complex to maintain them in the collection and remapping them after the ownership changes. While First one (I have never used) seems like can be done via configuration only.

Answer (score 0):

The checkbox option will appear once you click on Change Owner link on the account record's detail page. Please find the screenshot below:
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Shailesh,
Is it possible if I am updating thousands of ownership change via this checkbox?

Comment: @sanchit are you updating the thousands record via data loader ?